Why am I blocked for posting question?
When I want to post a question, I faced this page.  I went through deeper, I recommended that I should edit my previous questions by checking all of them and make them better.  I was shocked.  My direct feeling is "不教而诛".  If my questions were not good enough, they should not be posted in the first place.  They should be returned to the user, recommend the "not good enough" parts to be edited, ... etc.  Instead, they are posted, and after a while, you are punished because they are not "good enough".  I am not questioning the principle itself, I like it because this is a way to maintain the quality standard.  Excellent.  I am questioning the "standard" of this policy.  "Who" decided?  Wouldn't it be fair that the standard should be known to the users before they post a question?

When a user or a moderator vote to close a question, he or she has to give a reason before the vote can be submitted. We do not close questions without reason.

thanks a lot.  I think I have to post the screenshots, but I don't know how.  Please guide me.  It will help a lot for you to understand what faced.

Take a screenshot of your computer screen and save it, When you compose your post, you can click on the image icon (the one looked like the sun above mountains) to add an image to your post. Choose 'Browse' to upload the saved picture  from your computer, it will be added to your post

It's not only here; all the Stack Exchange sites are notorious for making the rules hard to find. Even when you do find them, they are arcane. Look at the big original site, Stack Overflow. There's nothing on the home page to indicate what the site is about or how to use it. If you are lucky, you'll find a small "?" in the upper right corner, and that might lead you to take their "tour", which helps a little but not much. New users will have many of their early posts to be downvoted or rejected. (Old users also get rejected, but not as often.)

To help maintain quality (and reduce user time spent on curation), Stack Exchange has both a question ban and an answer ban.  In this case, I think you've hit the question ban.  (Your questions are listed here.)  This is an automatic process (i.e., there's no human directly involved), and only Stack Exchange staff knows the precise algorithm.

Wouldn't it be fair that the standard should be known to the users before they post a question?

It's not straightforward to automatically pinpoint a single problem before posting (I'm not even sure this would be possible, e.g. there might be multiple overlapping problems).  I surmise that the question ban takes into account all of the user's questions, as suggested by the advice:

Edit all of your questions, paying special attention to those that score 0 or less.

and it likely treats downvotes, closed, and deleted questions as negatives (along with other features we're unaware of).
In general, well-received questions here tend to identify something specific the OP wants to learn about the Chinese language.  By reading the answers we learn something, and good questions attract such answers.

When I went through all my questions, yes, there were some downvotes.  But overall, they are fairly accepted and stimulated hot discussion.  I sincerely welcome anybody to view my questions to decide whether I deserve this "punishment" (whoever decided it.)

"stimulated hot discussion" is at odds with the general philosophy with Stack Exchange: This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat..  Stack Exchange is designed to inhibit discussion.

Thanks a lot for the info.  I wonder why I did not notice this principle when I first joined.  Is it expressed somewhere that I might neglect?  Can you guide me the remedy now?  The page asked my to check/edit all the questions I posted.  Isn't it already "history"?  What is the point to do this now that most of my previous questions are already read (or unwilling to read).  The users will re-read my posted questions?   Sorry, Becky, to trouble you like this.  But you always give me good advice and valid answers.

It looks like you're currently not banned.  In any case, diamond mods are unable to change these bans.  If your questions attract upvotes it'll probably be fine (although the algorithm is not known), so I encourage writing pinpointed, answerable questions: the question is specific, and when we read an answer, we can determine whether or not it answers the question.

Going to that direction from now on.  Much appreciated.
